# sed error while installing Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install gitlab on my server through apt-get(well, aptitude, really) and encountering the following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unknown option to `s'

That's after following the official instructions which wanted me to install the gitlab-ce package, which doesn't seem to exist.

How can I make this work?